# Rails link_to Creating Invalid Links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm using Ruby on Rails v4 and I'm having a weird issue that I haven't been able to track down the cause. I have a rails view in which I'm trying to make a simple link to a record. In my view I'm using

```
<%= link_to contact.first_name + " " + contact.last_name, contact %>
```

The result is an html link that looks like this

```
http://someurl.com/contact.5
```

which takes me to the contact page of my application instead of showing me the contact that has an ID of 5.

This is what my simplified routes.rb looks like

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root                'dashboard#index'
  get    'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get    'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get    'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'

  resources :customers
  resources :contacts

end
```

These are my routes:

```
       root GET    /                                       dashboard#index
       help GET    /help(.:format)                         static_pages#help
      about GET    /about(.:format)                        static_pages#about
    contact GET    /contact(.:format)                      static_pages#contact
  customers GET    /customers(.:format)                    customers#index
            POST   /customers(.:format)                    customers#create
new_customer GET    /customers/new(.:format)                customers#new
edit_customer GET    /customers/:id/edit(.:format)           customers#edit
   customer GET    /customers/:id(.:format)                customers#show
            PATCH  /customers/:id(.:format)                customers#update
            PUT    /customers/:id(.:format)                customers#update
            DELETE /customers/:id(.:format)                customers#destroy
   contacts GET    /contacts(.:format)                     contacts#index
            POST   /contacts(.:format)                     contacts#create
new_contact GET    /contacts/new(.:format)                 contacts#new
edit_contact GET    /contacts/:id/edit(.:format)            contacts#edit
            GET    /contacts/:id(.:format)                 contacts#show
            PATCH  /contacts/:id(.:format)                 contacts#update
            PUT    /contacts/:id(.:format)                 contacts#update
            DELETE /contacts/:id(.:format)                 contacts#destroy
```

When I use the same syntax as above to link to customers, the link works fine. What have I messed up and why does it send to me the contact page when the link says contact.5?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you've already defined a route that is providing a `contact_url` helper:

```
get    'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
```

This means you can use `contact_url` or `contact_path` to get the route to your static contact page.

When rails tries to link to an object it uses the url helper method for that object type. So when you do `link_to(..., contact)` it uses the existing `contact_url` method to generate the route.

You can see the difference in your `rake routes` output too (between customers and contacts). For customers you get a different output for the `#show` action line:

```
customer GET    /customers/:id(.:format)                customers#show
```

For contacts the `contact` but is missing:

```
         GET    /contacts/:id(.:format)                 contacts#show
```

because there is already a `contact` route defined.

You can get round the problem by defining a different name for your static contact route:

```
get 'contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', as: :static_contact
```

Comment: Thanks @Shadwell. I noticed that the customer and contacts were different when I ran rake routes, but I couldn't figure out why. Thanks also for showing me how to change it. I'm new to rails and this was helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Line in your route.rb gives this conflict:

```
get    'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
```